# How to use a method to a JOptionPane.showInputDialog in main with arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have an assignment to create a program where I need a series of methods that are called from main which are passed arrays.

I have 3 arrays.

I need to create a program which should have the arrays declared in the main and passed as arguments to methods.

All arrays should be passed as an argument to a method which asks for input.

So basically 2 methods including main.

Right now, my code looks a little like this, but it doesn't do what I need.

```
class testArrayMethod {

    public static void main(String [] params) {

            String[] array1 = {"Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5"};
            String[] array2 = {"1tseT","2tseT","3tseT","4tseT","5tseT"};
            int[] array3 = {5,10,15,20,25};

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yes or No?");
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, array_input(array1,array2,array3)); 

            System.exit(0);
    }

    public static String array_input(String[] a, String[] b, int[] c) {

            String q = "";

            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                    q += "Array 1: " + a[i] + "\n" + 
                         "Array 2: " + b[i] + "\n" + 
                         "Array 3: " + c[i] + "\n";
            }

            return q;
    }

}
```

Right now it prints all of the array information on to a single InputDialog, but I need it to print to 5 different ones, I need some sort of different loop mechanism I guess?

This is a university assignment so if you can somehow explain it to me without simply doing it I would really be glad, I want to understand and learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was doing wrong is trying to call the JOptionPane.showInputDialog in the main instead of just simply doing it in the array_input method.

I fixed the code by replacing

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, array_input(array1,array2,array3));
```

with

```
array_input(array1,array2,array3);
```

I then replaced the method from..

```
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                q += "Array 1: " + a[i] + "\n" + 
                     "Array 2: " + b[i] + "\n" + 
                     "Array 3: " + c[i] + "\n";
        }
```

to...

```
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                 q = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Array 1: " + a[i] + "\n" + 
                     "Array 2: " + b[i] + "\n" + 
                     "Array 3: " + c[i] + "\n");
        }
```